# Is it possible to add multiple attributes to a single axis in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I am creating a Power BI custom visual where in which we want to plot 3 or 4 attributes on a single y-axis.I have downloaded sample custom visuals but not able to figure out how to do it.

Please guide me in plotting multiple attributes on one axis.

Regards
C

Answer (score 0):

You need to either have a dataset that has a shared axis already (3-4 measures, one dimension), after which you can just select all of the attributes (measures) and add them to the visual using the dimension as axis.

If you have 3-4 seperate datasets with same axis, you need to join (merge in powerbi queryeditor) them based on their shared axis to plot them on the same visual.

I.e. the data needs to be within the same dataset for you to be able to plot it.